# Could not load type 'System.Web.UI.ParseChildrenAttribute' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Cult=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, runtime-error, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

My .NET 5 application after nuget update is facing an error when I run the application.

`TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.UI.ParseChildrenAttribute' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.`

[image: Error]

[image: NugetUpdate]

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the documentation `ParseChildrenAttribute Class` [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.parsechildrenattribute?view=netframework-4.8) the supported version is up to 4.8. You are using some packages or libraries that are dependent on this reference and that is why you can't upgrade to .Net 5.